# How to debug Python running on a local lighttpd server using Python Tools for Visual Studio (PTVS)

Tags: python, visual-studio, ptvs

Visual Studio has great python support via the Python Tools for Visual Studio:
http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Debugging python code in Visual Studio works as expected. I set up a lighttpd server on my local Windows machine, and I have python scripts running as cgi scripts. I would like to be able to debug these in Visual Studio (running on the same PC) when running from lighttpd.

I am able to debug the cgi scripts using:
http://winpdb.org
But I would prefer Visual Studio.

According to this question:
[How to debug a remote python application with (Python Tools for) Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7739381/how-to-debug-a-remote-python-application-with-python-tools-for-visual-studio)

It is implied there is almost a way, but I don't see a specific way to set a breakpoint and have it debugged in VS.

Comment: If this is just on your local machine does Debug->Attach to Process work for you?  In theory you can attach to the cgi process, set breakpoints, and start debugging.

Comment: Yes, Debug->Attach does work. I listed the steps in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. This does work, and works pretty well, once you get the steps down.

- Add a delay to the python source file like this:

  ```
  time.sleep(10)
  ```

  This is necessary if you are not using FastCGI, as the python process is probably going to start and finish long before you can attach to it. I assume this would be different with FastCGI, but I haven't reached that stage yet.
- Set a breakpoint in your python file that is running in your lighttpd (or apache?) server. I tested lighttpd. Note: If you don't add the source file to a project in VS, and thus don't set a breakpoint, you can still debug, but you'll have to force an error in the file. I added a line 'debugger' which worked.
- Load the page in a browser and allow the delay to be hit
- In VS: Debug -> Attach to process -> pythonw.exe (complete this before the delay elapses)

I added a short macro to the Visual Studio IDE that automates the procedure of attaching to pythonw.exe. I'll share that if anyone is interested.